# How to define a "false status" for a class in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have defined a class in Python 3 and have a case that I create an "empty" class object. Therefor I want to be able to check if the object is empty or not, like you can write:

```
test = []
if not test:
    print('False')
```

My code for the class looks like this (note that I will accept an empty value for name):

```
class myClass:
    def __init__(self, name=False):
        self.name = name

    def __str__(self):
         return self.name.replace('\n', ' ')

    def __repr__(self):
         return self.name.replace('\n', ' ')

    def __eq__(self, other):
         if not isinstance(other, myClass):
             return False

         if not self.name and not other.name:
              pass

         elif not (self.name or other.name):
              return False

         elif self.name != other.name:
                 return False

         return True
```

Now I would like to check if I got an empty class:

```
test = myClass()
if not test:
    print('False')
else:
    print('True')
```

The result of this case will always be true. How can I change this behaviour?

Comment: @GinoMempin If I get that correct, I would define __bool__(self) like if self == myClass() return False else return True and that would do the job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a [`__bool__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__bool__) method to your class:

```
def __bool__(self):
    return bool(self.name)
```

To cater for the case where `self.name == ''` and you want to return `True`:

```
def __bool__(self):
    return self.name is not False
```